# Is it possible to convert categorical measures to numerical measures in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api, categorical-data

I am attempting to use the `ZN()` function to detect any `NULL` values, but the measures I need to use are categorical.

They can either only hold one of two values  (`Valid` or `Invalid`) or be blank.

Is it possible for Tableau to treat these categorical values as numerical?

My first thought was to use a factorisation-type function, [like the one in R](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/classes/s133/factors.html), but I am not aware of any such function in Tableau.

Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create calculated field with following formula

```
CASE [YOUR_FIELD] 
    WHEN NULL THEN 0 
    WHEN 'Invalid' THEN 1 
    ELSE 2 END
```